# Mathematical notation on a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, matrix-equations, control-theory

Matrix notation question (in reference to "simultaneous interconnection and damping assignment passivity based control"):

We select an $n\times n$ matrix called $F_d(x)$. Let $G(x) := F_d(x)+F_d(x)^T$ under the constraint that the following inequality holds: $G(x) < 0$.

**My Question:** Does this mean that each element in $G(x)$ must be less than zero, or just the eigenvalues of $G(x)$ must be less than zero?

Comment: If possible you need to post the sepcific font of that equation.... different characters $<$ can mean different things.

Answer (score 2):

From my general memory of control system, it usually means negative definite, i.e. all eigenvalues are negative. Usually, it uses the symbol $ \prec$ some books just used $<$... depending on the convention.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix#Notation

Comment: This symbol is called "Loewner ordering".See p. 39 of this rich document : https://www.math.lsu.edu/~lawson/liecontrol.pdf

Comment: Also the fact that $G(x)$ is a symmetric matrix (assuming that $F_d(x)$ is real) would strengthen this hypothesis.